# How to delete part of an fbx model?

Tags: mesh, import

I have exported a mesh character from Unreal Engine 4 as a fbx file. I want to remove everything but the head.

I literally have no idea how to use Blender and the UI seems confusing and overwhelming.

Could anyone possibly tell me how to delete everything but the head, step-by-step.

[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9rwq96GHhcvSnJLQ1hLSURUMFE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is way too general

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, import the mesh by pressing *File > Import > FBX* and navigating to the .fbx file.

[image: Import an FBX model]

Once you have your object imported, ensure that it is the active object (orange outline). If it's not active, right click on it.

Then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode* where you can edit the underlying mesh.

In your case, you can select the parts of the mesh you want to delete by:

3. Selecting a vertex on the head with <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to select linked geometry
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to invert selection

Once you have the vertices you want to delete selected, press <kbd>Delete</kbd> *> Vertices* to delete them.

Comment: When I press Shift L it deselects the entire thing, and then when invert selection it would select the entire mesh. Why is this happening?

Comment: Thank you, been trying to figure this out for nearly 5+ hours :D

Comment: @Kevin Oops, I meant `Ctrl L`. `Shift L` *deselects* connected geometry.

Comment: Just note that some information might be lost when importing and exporting the model (such as some material or rig information) since the import and export code are for different versions and don't support the same features.